# Sharepoint Property Panel Add Button and show Added Items

Tags: spfx-webparts, web-part-property

I am trying to make Links applications. On the property Panel, the user can select what links to add on this web part.  After the user Selects the Title of the link, the user clicks Add.
I expect to have the Item/ List of Items shown in the web part.

Please kindly advise what was missing?
I checked on this.data there is value, however this.props.data is undefined.
I suspect because I didn't render it in the Webpart.ts, if so how to make it re-render?

WebPart.ts

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDom from "react-dom";
import { Version } from "@microsoft/sp-core-library";
import {
  PropertyPaneTextField,
  PropertyPaneCheckbox,
  PropertyPaneLabel,
  PropertyPaneLink,
  PropertyPaneSlider,
  PropertyPaneToggle,
  PropertyPaneDropdown,
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneButton
} from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";

import * as strings from "MylinkWebPartStrings";
import Mylink from "./components/Mylink";
import { IMylinkProps } from "./components/IMylinkProps";
import { PropertyPaneButtonType } from "@microsoft/sp-property-pane";

export interface IMylinkWebPartProps {
  description: string;
  linkName: string;
  add: any;
  data: any;
}

export default class MylinkWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<
  IMylinkWebPartProps
> {

  private data = [];

  private handleClick() {
    this.data = [...this.data, this.properties.linkName];
    this.context.propertyPane.refresh();
    this.onDispose();

    console.log(this.data);
    debugger;
  }
  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IMylinkProps> = React.createElement(
      Mylink,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        pagecontext: this.context.pageContext,
        SPHttpClient: this.context.spHttpClient,
        linkName: this.properties.linkName,
        add: this.properties.add,
        data: this.properties.data
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse("1.0");
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: ""
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: "Select Links to Add",
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneDropdown("linkName", {
                  label: "Title",
                  options: [
                    { key: "Select", text: "Select" },
                    { key: "google", text: "google" }
                  ]
                }),
                PropertyPaneTextField("URL", {
                  label: "URL"
                }),
                PropertyPaneButton("add", {
                  text: "Add Link",
                  buttonType: PropertyPaneButtonType.Primary,
                  onClick: this.handleClick.bind(this)
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Main.tsx

```
 public render(): React.ReactElement<IMylinkProps> {
    console.log(this.props);
    debugger;
    return (
      <div className={styles.mylink}>
        <div className={styles.container}>

          {this.props.data}
          {this.props.description}
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image: Property Panel]

Comment: Can you post the rest of your webpart.ts definition?  Specifically the `render` method of your webpart class is where the "magic" happens that translates your configuration webpart properties into the `props` for your component class.

Comment: @willman, thanks for your reply, I have updated the complete webpart.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are only missing one step.  You are updating your local `data []` member value, but you are not saving that back to your webpart properties

Try updating `handleClick` to the following:

```
  private handleClick() {
    this.data = [...this.data, this.properties.linkName];
    this.properties.data = this.data;

    this.context.propertyPane.refresh();
    this.onDispose();

    console.log(this.data);
    debugger;
  }
```

Comment: I have overlooked, thanks for reminding me !!!!!! It works